# Authentication with Google OAuth2 on custom API and mobile

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

In our service we are exposing `API` for sign in / sign up for the users.
We are using `OAuth2` with Google single sign on. The problem is that when user is using his Google credentials by the webapp (but not with our API) he is able to sign in, but when he is using his Google credentials on mobile our `API` in response send an error (Internal Server Error). What could be the case?

During the connection from mobile we are getting correct `auth_token` from Google this page confirms this:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

and this

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=

We are also able to retrive data about Google account (name, email etc) but when we are sending this `auth_token` to our `API` from mobile we are not getting authenticate.

API calls look like this:

```
{ "user": { "access_token": "ya29.JAGqm****", "provider": "google" } }
```

Required post strucutre:

```
POST /users/sign_in

{
   "user": {
     "access_token": "facebook or google access token",
     "provider": "google" | "facebook"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable Google+ API in [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

[image]